# Convert namedtuple parameters to utf8

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-unicode

Currently, I'm reading from a REST API in Python 2.7 and then process the JSON response and stored it a **namedtupled**.

The results are written in a CSV file.
Currently I'm getting this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Sample API response:

```
[u'private:bowlmorlanes', u'4983691', 30804108, u'20180604', u'Bowlmor AMF', 10753, 639.0, u'https://www.linkedin.com/company/4983691', u'Entertainment', u'20180604', u'20180604T155553Z', None, u'https://www.bowlmor.com', None, None]
```

Each of these items in list is processed as a namedtupled.

```
Product = collections.namedtuple('Product', [
    'ticker_symbol', 'entity', 'unique_id', 'as_of_date', 'company_name',
    'followers', 'items', 'linkedin', 'industry', 'date_added',
    'date_updated', 'description', 'website', 'sector', 'ticker_industry'
])
```

Processing response:

```
  response_rows = response_items.get('rows')  
  # Request JSON string contains summary of request.
  results = []
  for response_row in response_rows:
    logging.info(response_row)
    results.append(Product(*response_row))
  return results
```

Save results

```
def SaveDataSet(results: Sequence[Product], filename: str):
  """Writes results stored in Sequence into a file in CNS.

  Args:
    results: Results with app information.
    filename: Destination file.

  Raises:
    ValueError: Result list is empty.
    FileError: Unable to write filename.
  """
  if not results:
    raise ValueError('Result list is empty')
  logging.info('Saving results here: %s', filename)
  with open(filename, 'w+') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    filewriter.writerows(results)
  logging.info('URLs processed: %d.', len(results))


SaveDataSet(results, output_file)
```

**Question:**
What is the best way to convert each parameter in namedtuple using this function to prevent error:

```
def _ToString(value):
  """Returns a string type based on value variable type.

  Since we handle multiple languages we need to return a string type to write
  in file human readable character.

  Args:
    value: (None, str or unicode)

  Returns:
    A str or None if no input.
  """

  if not value:
    logging.warning('Empty value')
    return None

  if isinstance(value, unicode):
    return value.encode('utf-8')
  else:
    return str(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented this:

```
results.append(Product(*[_ToString(x) for x in response_row]))
```